# SVG Symbol in Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, sql, svg

i have few hundred records in table, i need to select them and add SVG symbol to correct one in QGIS.
I created new rule in in attribute table, then i wrote a simple rule (thats only two of much more)

```
"NAME" LIKE '%House%' OR "NAME" like '%Hotel%'
```

And my question is, what can i do to after selection add my saved SVG Symbols automaticly to correct type of building? (saved SVG have same name as a House and Hotel)..
Is it possible, to add some path to my SVG Symbol after every type of building or sth?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is a categorized symbology.
I have only used this based on an existing field. (For instance, you can create a Building_Type field that contain values such as 'House' or 'Hotel'.) But it seems you can also use expressions.

Go to Properties > Symbology. There, you can pick "Categorized" instead of "Single symbol". You then need to pick a value (either your building type field if you have one, or an expression). You can then replace the default "simple symbol" with "SVG symbol". Below the built-in library, there is the option to link a SVG file of your own.

I hope this helps.